# How to create GIF (which looks more natural) with dithering from video frames or Array of UIImages?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-image, dithering

Here is the link (https://imgplay.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029411991-What-is-GIF-Dithering-Option-) where it says `When you save the file as GIF with dithering, it can make your GIF more natural.`

How to implement `Dithering` for creating more natural GIF from UIImages or video frames using **Objective-C or Swift**?

Comment: Try searching something about Floyd Steinberg dithering algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering

Comment: I found this algorithm.  But failed to implement in swift /objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source image is 8-bit per channel RGB, you *could* use vImage. vImage doesn't have a `vImageConvert_RGB88toIndexed8`, but you can split your interleaved image into three 8-bit planar buffers for RGB. I don't know exactly how well this would work, but you could convert two of the three channels to `Indexed2` with [`vImageConvert_Planar8toIndexed2`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533017-vimageconvert_planar8toindexed2) and the other channel to `Indexed4` with [`vImageConvert_Planar8toIndexed4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533049-vimageconvert_planar8toindexed4). That would give you the required 8-bit lookup table.

Apple have loads of Accelerate sample code projects [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate). [Optimising Image-Processing Performance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/optimizing_image-processing_performance) discusses converting interleaved images to planar format. If you have a known palette, [Applying Color Transforms to Images with a Multidimensional Lookup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/applying_color_transforms_to_images_with_a_multidimensional_lookup_table) Table may be a solution to quantising your image to 256 colors.

Comment: I'm new to viImage. Even I didn't do anything with vImage. can you show an example? How to split image into 3 bit planner buffers and how to play with other functions that you provided? 
Thanks for your time and valuable references. @simon-gladman

Comment: Hi @sagarthecoder, I've added links to Apple docs to my answer.

Comment: ```vImageConvert_Planar8toIndexed2(argbSourcePlanarBuffers[1], argbDestinationPlanarBuffers[1], kvImageGetTempBufferSize, lookUpTable, kvImageConvert_DitherFloydSteinberg, kvImageNoFlags)``` 



it always shows ```Type of expression is ambiguous without more context```

Comment: You'll need to add some more information - what types are your parameters? Have you looked at the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533017-vimageconvert_planar8toindexed2)?

Comment: ...you might want to raise a new post tagged [vimage].